# Some commands that require internet access take too long to execute

Tags: networking, internet

Recently I noticed that some commands that require internet access take too long to execute on my Arch system. For example:

- `ssh ...` takes 3 minutes to ask me for password
- `pip install ...` takes 1 minute to start downloading package
- `npm install ...` hangs forever

But other like git, yay run immediately. These commands suddenly slowed down around week or two ago. Before they worked fine.

I tried reinstalling linux and tested it on Ubuntu and Manjaro using bootable USB but the result is the same. It can't be caused by slow internet connection because I usually have 40 Mb/s download and 10Mb/s upload. Currently I'm using EndeavourOS.

I tried setting my `/etc/resolv.conf` to just `8.8.8.8` (Google's public DNS server), but that didn't fix the speed issues.

I also tested it on Windows (I have dualboot with Windows and Linux) and there it works fine.

Full ouput of `ssh -vvv ...` till the place where it pauses:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/whistleroosh/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/whistleroosh/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "xxx" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup xxx:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx [yyy] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IPV6_TCLASS 0x48
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the cause of this slowdown?

Comment: Try running `ssh -v ...` and see what is happening.  There may be a DNS problem, or it may be trying IPv6, failing and they trying IPv4.  Without more information no-one will be able to help you.

Comment: What are the contents of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file? I haven't found the time to debug this, but for a while now, every time I connect to a new network (or restart, or just disconnect and connect again) something on my Arch changes `resolv.conf` to `::1`. Presumably NetworkManager. That just breaks it, in my case, but maybe you have it being set to a slow DNS? Try `udo sed -i.bak 's/::1/8.8.8.8/' /etc/resolv.conf` and see if that makes the commands any faster.

Comment: @terdon there are only 2 servers in `/etc/resolv.conf` One is just 192.168.100.1 and the other one is something with `::1` but changing it doesn't solve my issue

Comment: @Martin it gets stuck on this line `debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IPV6_TCLASS 0x48`

Comment: Try changing to Google's `8.8.8.8`, removing the others, and see if that speeds things up. That will at least tell us if the issue is there or not. You can always change back afterwards.

Comment: @terdon I tried it before but it doesn't change anything. Command still take too long to execute

Comment: Remember that if you are watching the output from the debug it is the command after the last one displayed that is sometimes causing the problem.  Also, if you are seeing `debug3` messages you must have used `ssh -vvv ...`, try just a single `-v`.

Comment: So it turns out it was indeed something with IPv6 because using `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` solved all the issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with IPv6. Disabling it e.g. by using `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Often when I see something like this it's due to name resolution timeout.  Would be a good thing to check.

- If you have /etc/nsswitch.conf, make sure no services are configured that you're not using.
- Check that configured DNS nameservers are correct.
- Do you have a local nameserver that handles reverse resolution?  Some services try to find your client's name for logging.  If the reverse resolution stalls, the server might hang during that time.

Comment: It doesn't loolk like it's caused by /etc/nsswitch.conf and DNS nameservers seem to be configured correctly. And I don't have any local nameserver

Comment: As mentioned above, you should show the output of `ssh -v` in your question and indicate where the pauses are.  It could be trying to hit IPv6 addresses then falling back to ipv4.  (could try `ssh -4 ...` and see if it differs.

Comment: `ssh -4 ...` solved the issue! But there are still problems with pip and npm

Comment: It actually was something with IPv6 because using `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1` solved all the issues. Now everything executes quickly. Though I have no idea why ipv6 suddenly caused problems